# angular 4 open dialog with remote url return value

Tags: angular

I have an angular 4 application and I want to open in new window  a remote url - url from other app that return value.
something like window.showModalDialog but in angular 4.

So, how can I open window with remote url that return value?

Comment: For modal you can use [ngx-bootstrap's modals](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) with an `IFrame` in it's template. What ever value that URL returns you can process it in it's component.

Comment: how can i get return value from iframe?

Comment: How your remote url is sending values?

Comment: by window.returnValue.
for example:
`window.returnValue = '0';
    window.close();`
i get value 0 from opend window.